# Adding AD Security Group into SharePoint Group with PnP Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions

Is there a way to use Add-PnPUserToGroup command to add a AD Security Group into a SharePoint group on SharePoint Online?

I'm writing a script which does some post-some creation tasks and just after a way to do this without writing lines and lines of code. I saw one-liner examples of adding security groups as site collection admins, but haven't found a way to add this to a SP Group.

When I try `Add-PnPUserToGroup -LoginName` parameter I get an:

> Add-PnPUserToGroup : The object is used in the context different from
> the one associated with the object.

Error so I think I may be doing something daft there!

I would really appreciate help on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the Connection parameter here you need to pass in the context of site for which you are executing the command which can be obtained by using `-ReturnConnection` switch

```
$connection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com -Credentials (Get-Credential) -ReturnConnection

Add-PnPUserToGroup -LoginName user@company.com -Connection $connection #variable form above line
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this now

Answer (score 1):

That cmdlet is used to add to a SharePoint group. To add to an Azure AD group, use [Add-AzureADGroupMember](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0). For Active Directory, use [Add-ADGroupMember](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps).

Comment: Sorry- got confused. I have to add and Azure Ad security group to a SharePoint Group

Comment: In that case, try https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639265/1760623.